# angular 2 remove an extra character from JSON response

Tags: angular, typescript

I get following response from my Django backend:

```
[{u'lat': 53.12258796536196, u'lng': 8.335471451282501}, {u'lat': 53.1225300194776, u'lng': 8.335511684417725}, {u'lat': 53.12250346092115, u'lng': 8.335405737161636}, {u'lat': 53.12256301644911, u'lng': 8.33535611629486}]
```

I handle it as follows:

```
response => {       

        this.exhibitionSurveyObjects = response;
        console.log(this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[0].path) <== this line print
        for(var i = 0; i < this.exhibitionSurveyObjects.length; i++){

          myVar.push(JSON.parse(this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[i].path)) 

        }

        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: myVar,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: this.map
        });
      },
```

Here I get an error on my console saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2` i.e. character 'u' is basically unexpected?

How can I get rid of it? perhaps how can I remove this 'u' character or any other way?

Comment: The error not that there is a 'u' character, it is that the keys in your object are not double quoted. Even if you remove the 'u' character you will not have valid JSON. It should look something like: [{"lat":53.1221234....`. What are you using to serialize the response into JSON? Please include some of your server side code,

Answer (score 0):

General string handling¶

Whenever you use strings with Django – e.g., in database lookups, template rendering or anywhere else – you have two choices for encoding those strings. You can use Unicode strings, or you can use normal strings (sometimes called “bytestrings”) that are encoded using UTF-8.

In Python 3, the logic is reversed, that is normal strings are Unicode, and when you want to specifically create a bytestring, you have to prefix the string with a ‘b’. As we are doing in Django code from version 1.5, we recommend that you import unicode_literals from the **future** library in your code. Then, when you specifically want to create a bytestring literal, prefix the string with ‘b’.

Python 2 legacy:

my_string = "This is a bytestring"
my_unicode = u"This is an Unicode string"

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/unicode/